# What do these statements mean in the MS β exam 70-461 "skills measured" list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have registered for the upcoming beta exam 70-461 entitled *Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012*.

I've been reading through the exam overview and found a bunch of descriptions I'm not exactly sure what some of the items mean:

- Create and alter DML triggers.

  - This objective may include but is not limited to: inserted and deleted tables; nested triggers; types of triggers; **update functions**; **handle multiple rows in a session**; performance implications of triggers
- Query data by using SELECT statements.

  - This objective may include but is not limited to: use the ranking
    function to select top(X) rows **for multiple categories** in a single
    query; write and perform queries efficiently using the new code items
    such as synonyms and joins (except, intersect); implement logic which
    uses dynamic SQL and system metadata; write efficient, technically
    complex SQL queries, including all types of joins versus the use of
    derived tables; determine what code may or may not execute based on
    the tables provided; **given a table with constraints, determine which
    statement set would load a table**; use and understand different data
    access technologies; CASE versus ISNULL versus COALESCE

The problem here I think is with the wording, which I think I'm not able to fully understand.

If someone could clarify these I'd be most grateful.

To put it as an actual question:

What is Microsoft talking about on the above highlighted statements?

Comment: Here's a link to the exam's page: http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-461&Locale=en-us#tab2

Comment: The ***"to select top(X) rows for multiple categories in a single query"*** type of queries has a tag in SO: [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/greatest-n-per-group/info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. DML - refers to data manipulation (update, insert, delete). A DML trigger is a trigger created to happen on update, insert or delete of table data.

The update function is the part of a DML trigger where you test if a required update has occured.

For Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myupdate_trigger
ON mytable
FOR UPDATE AS
if UPDATE(column_1)
BEGIN
-- Do something
END
```

This will trigger a further action every time column column_1 is updated in table mytable. The update function is UPDATE(column_1).

Answer (score 2):

The exam (and the descriptions) are in beta.  They are all subject to change before the actual exam is released.  Welcome to the joy of beta testing Microsoft exams.

Comment: So what? Your "answer" is not helpful to the least.

Comment: So they will go through and clean up the language and make things more clear after they get through the beta process.